# How to pass datetime in dynamic query in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have written a stored procedure like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLoadPendingPaymentSheetByFilter] --'2015-04-01','2015-04-02','Select-One','Select-One','Select-One',''   
    @FromDate as datetime,
    @ToDate as datetime,
    @Status as nvarchar(50),
    @Remarks as nvarchar(50),
    @Paymenttype as nvarchar(50),
    @BillID as nvarchar(50)      
AS 
    Declare @Where as nvarchar(max)

    set @Where = '( MenifestDate BETWEEN  ''' +   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@FromDate, 101) + ''' and ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ToDate, 101) + ''' )'

    if(@Status <> 'Select-One')
       set @Where = 'Status = '+ @Status 

    if(@Remarks <> 'Select-One')
       set @Where = @Where + 'and Remarks = '+ @Remarks 

    if(@Paymenttype <> 'Select-One')
       set @Where = @Where + 'and PaymentType = ' + @Paymenttype 

    if(@BillID <> '')
       set @Where = @Where + 'and BillID = '+ @BillID 

    Declare @SelectString as nvarchar(1000)  
    set @SelectString = 'SELECT MasterID,BillID, MenifestDate, FarwardingNo,ReceverCountryName,Status,Remarks,PaymentType    
     FROM tblMenifest   
     WHERE ' + @Where

     exec @SelectString
```

When I execute it I got this error

> The name 'SELECT MasterID,BillID, MenifestDate, FarwardingNo,ReceverCountryName,Status,Remarks,PaymentType FROM tblMenifest WHERE ( MenifestDate BETWEEN  '04/01/2015' and '04/02/2015' )' is not a valid identifier

The `MenifestDate` column datatype is `datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to put `EXEC(@SelectString)` rather than `exec @SelectString`.